# Best way to persist firebase login using expo go

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to make an app in React Native using **Expo Go.** have successfully gotten google sign in working and it's all good. Unfortunately, the user's login does NOT persist between app relaunches. At first, I thought it was an async storage problem, but I can save items in storage just fine between relaunches.

What data would I need to save manually to be able to log the user back in whenever the app launches?

I would prefer to persist the data manually, as all the methods that are *supposed* to work, do not work for me. Methods I have tried:

- Calling `setPersistence(getAuth(), browserLocalPersistence)` gives me an error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502662/react-native-firebase-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-storage-setit) post for the exact error that I am getting.
- Using `onAuthStateChanged` also does not work for me, in fact, that is the main way I know when to log in. The user object is just always null, and never changes from null until the user logs in again (which happens on every app launch).

  ```
  useEffect(() => getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(value => {
    if (value) {
      console.log("User is signed in");
    }  else {
      console.log("User is signed out");
      // navigation.navigate("login")
    }
  }), [])
  ```

(This code will always print user is signed out on app relaunch.)
At this point, I think it would just be easier if I could just save the user's credentials myself and then log them in silently on app launch. I am having a hard time finding code to do this.

Comment: I have that library installed, my question is what data do I need to save to keep the user persistent

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, so I realized that to preserve login state, you actually have to do a special process if using expo. You need to initialize your own auth, passing in Async Storage, like so

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"

const defaultApp = initializeApp(config);
initializeAuth(defaultApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});
```

Comment: Any idea what this should look like with the firebase 9 SDK (using compat)?

Comment: @Irfy did you ever figure out how to implement with  firebase 9 SDK (using compat) ?

Comment: is it safe? I think AsyncStorage doesn't encrypt data

Comment: is there any way to know if persisted user loaded?
I want this to show a splash screen while persistent user loading.

Comment: @CagriUysal See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: @BernardAllotey hi i keep getting `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/already-initialized).`

Comment: @kd12345 By using `export const auth = initializeAuth(app, { persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage) });`, as @pagey mentioned in another response below, you get rid of the FirebaseError.

Comment: "firebase/auth/react-native" has not been removed, what do I need to change in this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76793627/unable-to-resolve-module-firebase-auth-react-native

Answer (score 11):

@Bernard Allotey's answer is correct.
Here is an example with the compat version of firebase 9

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/functions';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {initializeAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
import {getReactNativePersistence} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';

import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

const fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.firestore();
firebase.functions();
// firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
initializeAuth(fireApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});

export default firebase;
```

Comment: hi i keep getting `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/already-initialized).`

Comment: Me too! Keep getting the auth/already-initalized error

Comment: use this `if(!firebase.apps.length) {firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)}` to get rid of the already initialized error.

Comment: Unable to resolve "firebase/auth/react-native"

Answer (score 6):

@Bernard Allotey's answer worked for me. However, I replaced

```js
export const auth = getAuth(app)
```

With

```js
export const auth = initializeAuth(app, { persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage) });
```

This gets around the error of `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/already-initialized).`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `SecureStore` to presist the data in the device. Something like `LocalStorage` in web, `SharedPreference` in Android and `NSUserDefaults` in iOS.

Example:

```
// save your thing
async function save(key, value) {
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value); 
}

// get your thing
async function getValueFor(key) {
  let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
  if (result) {
    alert(" Here's your value  \n" + result);
  } else {
    alert('No values stored under that key.');
  }
}
```

Read more here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

the idea is, save the JWT from Firebase in the SecureStore, so when the app start, check for this value, then use that JWT in secure store when calling to your API

Comment: I appreciate this attempt at an answer, but I know how to save strings to storage. I'm specifically asking about how to persist a firebase login across app launches

Comment: @BernardAllotey the idea is, save the JWT from Firebase in the SecureStore, so when the app start, check for this value, then use that JWT in secure store when calling to your API

Comment: @ken How should we handle JWT expiry though? Is there a way to easily refresh the JWT when it expires?

Comment: Unfortunately the expo-secure-store prevent us from storing with key contains these characters: `.` `-` `_`. More info :https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/#securestoresetitemasynckey-value-options

So by passing SecureStore to authentication, it throw the error.
Issue screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/38828503?key=a8aaac420766da913aac154a451b63c9